# How can I return Many to One relation data joined with One to One data?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a question concerning Laravel schema. 
Was that a bad idea to create an additional one-to-one table user_description, to store additional user data? Here is my schema:

[image]

For example now I don't know how to use eager loading to get user_photos if at first I retrieve topics' data.

Here is the code I use to get the last topics with user data:

```
return  Topic::with('blog', 'user')->orderBy('topics.id', 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: well, i dont see any benefit in sourcing that property out? Why did you do that?

Comment: Actually there are a lot of other fields. I have just only pointed this one to make it look simpler. I thought that there should be a benefit to the database speed in case it hits a lot of queries when having millions of rows. Should I simply merge those two tables (users and user_description) and don't bother with one-to-one joining in that particular case?

Comment: I think this cannot be answered simply like that. I personally like to go normalized. There are plenty of ways to increase query-performance other than splitting tables (e.g. Indices).

Comment: Merging the tables is really not an issue - I can do it any moment, just was wondering if splitting has any advantages and if it is possible to retrieve the data from it in the one I have described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your `User`-Model has a relation `description()` I suppose this does what you want.

```
return Topic::with('blog', 'user', 'user.description')->orderBy('topics.id', 'DESC')->get();
```

the concept is called sth. like eager loading of nested-relationships and is documented at the bottom of the [eager loading documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading) of laravel

Comment: it does exactly what I wanted. Thanks.